# Is there a way to name the file that is downloaded from a URL call in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, servicenow

I am using this link to pull a `csv` file from Service now with excel vba

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url https://xxxxxxx.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id=676dbfdadb2637489ec9de1a489xxxxx")
```

It downloads the file directly to users downloads but I am wondering is there any way you can set the name of the downloaded file, kind of like save as function?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use CURL
Download it here:
https://curl.haxx.se/windows/

This is the sample:

```
Shell("c:\curl.exe https://xxxxxxx.service-now.com/sys_report_template.do?CSV&jvar_report_id=676dbfdadb2637489ec9de1a489xxxxx -o output-name-xxxx.csv")
```

Hope it helps.